# Passing a Piecewise function of NIntegrate through NIntegrate?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

I am trying to pass a piecewise numerical integral (function1) through another numerical integral (function2). When I try this, however, I receive an error that says "t = T is not a valid limit of integration." So, it seems that function1 is not "receiving" the values that are being passed to it from function2. Is there a solution to this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Alex

```
a = 0.03; b = d = 1; c = 0.5; K = HMax = 2000; v = 10^(-7);

function1[g_, t0_] := Block[{HandX1, h7, HandX2, h8, B3},

HandX1 = DSolve[{H'[t] == -a*H[t], H[0] == HMax, 
X'[t] == X[t]*b*H[t]/HMax - X[t]*d*X[t]/K, X[0] == K}, {H[t], 
X[t]}, t]; h7 = HandX1[[1]][[1]][[2]];

B3[u_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[h7*t, {t, t0, u}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];

HandX2 = DSolve[{H'[u] == -a*H[u], H[0] == HMax, 
X'[u] == X[u]*b*H[u]/HMax - X[u]*d*X[u]/K, X[0] == K}, {H[u], 
X[u]}, u]; h8 = HandX2[[1]][[1]][[2]];

Piecewise[{{0, g < 0.2}, {2/(1 + NIntegrate[Exp[-B3[u]]*h8/K, {u, t0, 5000},Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]), g >= 0.2}}]]

function2[g_] :=Block[{},1 - Exp[-v*
NIntegrate[function1[g, T], {T, 0, 500}, 
 Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]]]

function2[0.4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several messages when using `DSolve[]`

```
In[15]:= DSolve[{H'[u] == -a*H[u], H[0] == HMax, 
  X'[u] == X[u]*b*H[u]/HMax - X[u]*d*X[u]/K, X[0] == K}, {H[u], 
  X[u]}, u]

During evaluation of In[15]:= Solve::incnst: Inconsistent or redundant transcendental equation. After reduction, the bad equation is -2000+Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1] == 0.

During evaluation of In[15]:= Solve::incnst: Inconsistent or redundant transcendental equation. After reduction, the bad equation is -2000+Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1] == 0.

During evaluation of In[15]:= Solve::incnst: Inconsistent or redundant transcendental equation. After reduction, the bad equation is -2000+Log[E^Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]] == 0.

During evaluation of In[15]:= General::stop: Further output of Solve::incnst will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[15]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

Out[15]= {{H[u] -> 2000 E^(-3 u/100), 
  X[u] -> (6000 E^(100/3 - 100/3 E^(-3 u/100)))/(
   3 + 100 E^(100/3) ExpIntegralEi[-(100/3)] - 
    100 E^(100/3) ExpIntegralEi[-(100/3) E^(-3 u/100)])}}
```

If all these acceptable, then we can use code

```
a = 3/100; b = d = 1; c = 1/2; K = HMax = 2000; v = 10^(-7);

function1[g_, t0_] := 
 Module[{HandX1, h7, HandX2, h8, B3}, 
  HandX1 = DSolve[{H'[t] == -a*H[t], H[0] == HMax, 
      X'[t] == X[t]*b*H[t]/HMax - X[t]*d*X[t]/K, X[0] == K}, {H[t], 
      X[t]}, t] // Quiet; h7 = HandX1[[1]][[1]][[2]] // Quiet;
  B3[u_?NumericQ] := 
   NIntegrate[h7*t, {t, t0, u}, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
  HandX2 = 
   DSolve[{H'[u] == -a*H[u], H[0] == HMax, 
      X'[u] == X[u]*b*H[u]/HMax - X[u]*d*X[u]/K, X[0] == K}, {H[u], 
      X[u]}, u] // Quiet; h8 = HandX2[[1]][[1]][[2]] // Quiet;
  f1[t1_?NumericQ] := 
   Piecewise[{{0, 
      g < 0.2}, {2/(1 + 
         NIntegrate[Exp[-B3[u]]*h8/K, {u, t1, 5000}, 
          Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]), 
      g >= 0.2}}]; f1[t0]]
function2[g_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{}, 
  f2 = 1 - Exp[-v*
      NIntegrate[function1[g, T], {T, 0, 500}, 
       Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]]; f2]
```

Check how it works

```
function2[0.4]

(*Out[]= 0.0000999949*)
```